# How to return early before executing all useEffects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!_editor.current) return
    _editor.current.setData(props.data)
  }, [props.data])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!_editor.current) return
    _editor.current.setReadOnly(props.readOnly)
  }, [props.readOnly])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!_editor.current) return
    _editor.current.container.setStyles(props.style)
  }, [props.style])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!_editor.current) return
    attachEventHandlers()
  })
```

As you can see here, all useEffects return if there is no `_editor.current`. Is there a way to write the logic `if (!editor.current) return` once instead of in each effects, like a middleware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a custom hook that takes care of conditional execution for you

```
const useConditionalEffect = (callback, deps) => {
   useEffect(() => {
       // conditionally use instead of early return
       if (_editor.current) {
          callback()
       }
   }, deps)
}
```

and use it like

```
useConditionalEffect(() => {
    _editor.current.setData(props.data)
  }, [props.data])

  useConditionalEffect(() => {
    _editor.current.setReadOnly(props.readOnly)
  }, [props.readOnly])

  useConditionalEffect(() => {
    _editor.current.container.setStyles(props.style)
  }, [props.style])

  useEffect(() => {
    attachEventHandlers()
  })
```

**P.S.** You must note that you not return from useEffect  because the return value which should be a function is a treated as a cleanup function.